# Why do convex lenses have a focal point?

Tags: optics, lenses

Why do convex lenses have a focal point? How to prove mathematically that all the parallel rays that hit the lens meet at a single point? I can't see to have an easy solution to prove it.

Comment: Can you outline what you have done so far to find the answer?

Comment: Why can't you prove it? It has been proved over decades. Parallel rays converge at that point. Isn't that enough to design any experiment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: look up thin lens approximation - done in most intro textbooks

Answer (score 1):

In general, I don't think it's true that you get a perfect focus for any convex lens...certainly not for the spherically ground lenses typically used in eyeglasses. Of course over a small region along the axis of symmetry, there will always be a limiting case focus.

Comment: Computer-designed, acrylic, aspheric lens elements do a *much* better job than spherical, glass lenses.

Comment: And after we've done as @james suggests we then *also* switch to using compound optics made of multiple materials to also reduce the chromatic aberration. And at that point things have gotten to be pretty expensive.